# Split Violin with 2 different X Value Scales

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

For a split violin in Seaborn, is it possible to reference a different X scale for each of the 2 sides of the violin?  If so, how is it accomplished?

Comment: The answer is yes. You may plot the same plot twice one of which to a `twinx` axes and remove some of the violins. Or you you move some of the violins over to a `twinx` axes.